# Как найти элемент, используя js?

Tags: javascript, java, javafx

Нужно найти элемент, используя js, в котором текст равен к примеру "San Jose Earthquakes".

```
String xpath = "//*[contains(text(),\"San Jose Earthquakes\")]";
webEngine.executeScript("document.evaluate('"+xpath+"', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).click();");
webEngine.executeScript("document.evaluate('//*[text()=\'San Jose Earthquakes\']', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE).click()");
```

Это не помогает, кидается эксепшнами :(
Один из них

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Еще пробовал такое

```
webEngine.executeScript("document.evaluate('//*[contains(child::text(), \"San Jose Earthquakes\")]/child::text()', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);");
```

Ошибок никаких нет, но как кликнуть по элементу, если конечно что-то нашлось

Пробую так `webEngine.executeScript("document.evaluate('//*[contains(child::text(), \"San Jose Earthquakes\")]/child::text()', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.click();");`

Но получаю ошибку

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" netscape.javascript.JSException: Error: TYPE_ERR: DOM XPath Exception 52
at com.sun.webkit.dom.JSObject.fwkMakeException(JSObject.java:128)
at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.twkExecuteScript(Native Method)
at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.executeScript(WebPage.java:1439)
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.executeScript(WebEngine.java:982)
at com.valeobet.client.strategies.Bet365Strategy$1.lambda$run$0(Bet365Strategy.java:33)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$49(GtkApplication.java:139)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
webEngine.executeScript("document.evaluate('//*[contains(text(), \"1/500\")]', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext().click();");
```

Решено.